# Getting MassAssignment error even after setting values as fillable with $guarded = [] in model

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to do a simple MassAssignment of values but I'm getting the error "Add [_token] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\Order]."

Even though I've already set all attributes to fillable in the Order model:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $guarded= [];

}
```

I've also tried the alternative of using  protected $fillable with a number of attributes but that gives the same error.

I've also tried both way to fill the data in de OrderController.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$data = $request->all();

Order::create($data);

// $order = new Order;
// $order->fill($data);
}
```

I've spent quite a bit of time looking for an answer but all I'm finding is 'set your attributes to fillable in the model', which I did. It just isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $data = $request->except('_token');
   Order::create($data);
}
```

Comment: Even a short explanation would make it perfectly legal.